# How to set page margins for ODT export in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode, odt

I think the margins in the `.odt` documents I export with Emacs and `org-mode` are too big.

How can I change them? Is there a special `#+OPTION` that `org-mode` provides for this?

[image: Margin of exported document in LibreOffice]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [relevant section](http://orgmode.org/manual/Applying-custom-styles.html) of the `org-mode` manual, you can customize the default layout for `.odt` documents by following these steps:

1. Create a new `.org` file (e.g. `styles.org`) with the following contents:

   ```
    #+OPTIONS: H:10 num:t
   ```

   ... and export it to ODT.
2. Open the file in LibreOffice Writer and bring up the "Styles and Formatting" window (by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> or by clicking on "Format" and then on "Styles and Formatting").
3. Customize the styles to your liking. For changing the page margins, navigate to the "Page Styles" tab:

   [image: Styles and Formatting window, Page Styles tab]

   ... right click "Default Style" and choose "Modify". In the window that comes up, navigate to the "Page" tab:

   [image: Page tab]

   ... and adjust the "Inner" and "Outer" margins to your liking. Click "OK" when you are done.
4. Save the file as an `.odt` or `.ott` file.
5. Add the following line to the top of the `.org` file for which you want the ODT exporter to use your custom styles:

   ```
   #+ODT_STYLES_FILE: "/path/to/exported/styles.odt"
   ```

   You can also tell `org-mode` to make your styles the default for every document you export to ODT by adding the following to your Emacs configuration:

   ```lisp
   (setq org-odt-styles-file "/path/to/exported/styles.odt")
   ```